# Regrading segments in planar graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, proof-explanation, planar-graphs

I've been reading [this](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/ImplementationPlanarity.pdf) paper about linear time planarity testing algorithm.  I have a question about two terms authors use throught the whole paper.

What is a segment and what is a subsegment?

I haven't managed to found its definitions in the paper.

These words first appear at the page 10 of the original document item 18.

[image]

The newer version can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2595990_An_Implementation_of_the_Hopcroft_and_Tarjan_Planarity_Test_and_Embedding_Algorithm).

Comment: Segments are defined on page 30, under item 42 "some theory".

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks!